# What does $P(\overline{N})$ mean?

Tags: probability, notation

Sorry, this must be laughably trivial, but I have to be sure. I am a grade 12 math tutor, and while running through some older exam questions I encountered this problem:

$$\text{If } P\left(N\right) = \frac{1}{4}\text{, determine } P\left(\overline{N}\right)$$

The multiple choice answers are:

$$\text{A. }\frac{-1}{4}\quad\text{B. }\frac{1}{4}\quad\text{C. }\frac{3}{4}\quad\text{D. }4$$

I eliminated **A** and **D**, because $0 \leq P(\text{Anything}) \leq 1$. My intuition tells me that $P\left(\overline{N}\right) = P\left(\lnot N\right)$ so the answer is **C**. [Wolfram says](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Macron.html) that the bar could mean the arithmetic mean of a set of values or negation of a logical expression. Either way I would like some clarification on this notation.

Comment: In this context, I'm sure it means the complement of $N$, that is, the probability of not-$N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general,
$\bar N$
means the complement
of $N$
(i.e., everything except $N$).

So,  $P(N)=1/4$
means that the probability of $N$ happening
is $1/4$.

Therefore
$P(\bar N)$
means the probability
of everything except $N$,
and this is $1-P(N) = 3/4$.